# How do you disable webhook on stripe dashboard?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have multiple stripe webhooks called. I can't find a way to enable/disable the webhook other than deleting it.

Is there an option on stripe to enable/disable webhook?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the existing answer refers to an older version of the Stripe API, but now you can enable/disable webhooks programatically (and probably via the website too)

https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/update

You set the argument `disabled` to either True or False to enable/disable

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to disable any created webhook**

But when Stripe couldn't send successfully to an endpoint for **several times**, then the webhook will automatically be disabled. But this disabled webhook can be enabled from the dashboard.

Comment: There was no explicit statement regarding this. And there is no direct/indirect way to do this unless in future Stripe will provide something.

Comment: I mean I couldn't find. But this is my statement